# display a list of dropdown relevant to the item you're hovering.

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Having a difficult time creating a dropdown nav in pure javascript. No jquery.

The menu should begin with a single button that reveals a drop-down
with 5 menu items when you hover over it. Hovering over one of the 5 menu items should reveal a second drop-down menu to the right of the original menu with an additional 5 items.

The issue im having is how to target the immediate child of the nav item being hovered.

For example, If i hover over the first item, then the sub dropdown would be displayed. but it doesnt work for the second item and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

HTML

```
<section class="dropdown-container">
  <button id="dropdown-trigger">Dropdown</button>
    <nav class="dropdown-list none">
      <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>
        <span class="nav-link"> Item</span>
          <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
            <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
              <li>5</li>
           </ul>
       </li>

       <li>
         <span class="nav-link">Item/span>
         <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>3</li>
           <li>4</li>
           <li>5</li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li>
          <span class="nav-link">Item</span>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
              <li>5</li>
           </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <span class="nav-link">Item</span>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
              <li>5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <span class="nav-link">Item</span>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
              <li>5</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
var button = document.getElementById('dropdown-trigger'),
    dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown'),
    dropdownList = document.querySelector('.dropdown-list'),
    navLink = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link'),
    link = document.querySelector('.dropdown'),
    subDropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-dropdown');


button.addEventListener('mouseover', displayDropdown);
button.addEventListener('mouseout', removeDropdown);

function displayDropdown() {
  dropdownList.classList.toggle('none');
}

function removeDropdown() {
  dropdownList.classList.toggle('none');
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/1dx73fy6/

Comment: You don't have permissions to use Jquery ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Im trying to learn strictly js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/nicksprague/f3mxydfq/3/

```
var button = document.getElementById('dropdown-trigger'),
dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown'),
//getElementsByClassName isn't supported past IE 9
//getElementsByTagName is more reliable 
//www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp
//www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp
 dropdown_ = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

 //addeventlistener isn't supported in versions of IE past 9 
 //www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp
 button.onmouseover = displayDropdown;
 button.onmouseout = removeDropdown;

for(var i = 0; i < dropdown_.length; i++){

if(dropdown_[i].className === 'dropdown_'){
    dropdown_[i].onmouseover = function(){
        var drop = this.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        //classList isn't supported past IE 10 
        //www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp
        //www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp
        drop.className = 'sub-dropdown';
    }
    dropdown_[i].onmouseout = function(){
        var drop = this.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        drop.className = 'sub-dropdown none';  
    }
}
}

function displayDropdown() {
   dropdown.className = 'dropdown';
}

function removeDropdown() {
   dropdown.className = 'dropdown none';
}
```

```
<nav id="dropdown-trigger" class="dropdown-list ">

 <button>Dropdown</button>

   <!--change the the trigger event to the actual menu so that hovering over the sub menu doesn't change main menu state-->

  <ul id='dropdown' class="dropdown none">
      <!--add 'none' class an 'dropdown' id to the ul element-->

    <li class="dropdown_">
        <!--add class to each dropdown item-->
      <span class="nav-link">Home</span>
      <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown_">
      <span class="nav-link">About</span>
      <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li class="dropdown_">
      <span class="nav-link">Rentals</span>
      <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown_">
      <span class="nav-link">Design</span>
      <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown_">
      <span class="nav-link">Work</span>
      <ul class="sub-dropdown none">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: add using code snippet so that anyone can run it here.

Comment: @Nick how would you add animation to the dropdown?

Comment: @RichardBustos [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2q29mmkp/) sorry for the sloppy code but it should give you the right idea.  as a side note... is there a particular reason you're doing this in JS?  I think a pure CSS method would suit your needs.